# Sniffing out base URL for suburls for custom search bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am seeking to create a search bar using JavaScript;

**That would essentially sniff the sub-urls of a website.**

*For instance;*

- If you typed in 'Los Angeles, CA' within the search field.
- Without having to manually create a database of url suffixes in a
  array; of every city to grab.
- I could write something in JavaScript; where the 'Los Angeles, CA' is
  read; and..
- sniffs out from based URL http://www.last.fm/
- And finds and redirects to: http://www.last.fm/search?q=Los+Angeles&from=ac

**I am thinking; something like; if 'what is entered' + 'somehow' to generate the suffix search?q=Los+Angeles&from=ac'**

Comment: It's possible if you know the exact format of the URL you are trying to reconstruct (parse the search entry, build the last.fm url with it accordingly) but there is no magic solution beyond that, and you will have to consider that most users won't give you input in the exact format you want.

Comment: Also, anything is possible... Stack Overflow is about code and implementation not broad ideas.  Get started writing this JS and we can help you along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontend guru Chris Coyier has written an excellent tutorial on this topic as it applies to JavaScript: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

I have used this technique before. One this to keep in mind is that this will not get you the query string.